# Why are inclusion guards used in vim plugins?

Tags: plugin-system

I see the following common pattern in the beginning of vim plugins (where `NAME` is a placeholder for some plugin identifier):

```
if exists("g:loaded_NAME")
  finish
endif

let g:loaded_NAME = 1
```

For example:
https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch/blob/75efe06ccc63b7cd50b193b99cce83e3ad3e60cb/plugin/eunuch.vim#L5-L8

Presumably this type of guard is intended to prevent the script from executing multiple times. I am curious why such a guard is necessary. In what scenarios would a plugin load multiple times?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It allows the user to disable a specific plugin.
See `:h use-cpo-save`, and search for `NOT LOADING`:

> NOT LOADING
>
> It's possible that a user doesn't always want to load this plugin.  Or the
>   system administrator has dropped it in the system-wide plugin directory, but a
>   user has his own plugin he wants to use.  Then the user must have a chance to
>   disable loading this specific plugin.  This will make it possible:
>
> ```
> 6 if exists("g:loaded_typecorr")
> 7   finish
> 8 endif
> 9 let g:loaded_typecorr = 1
> ```
>
> This also avoids that when the script is loaded twice it would cause error
>   messages for redefining functions and cause trouble for autocommands that are
>   added twice.
>
> The name is recommended to start with "loaded_" and then the file name of the
>   plugin, literally.  The "g:" is prepended just to avoid mistakes when using
>   the variable in a function (without "g:" it would be a variable local to the
>   function).
>
> Using "finish" stops Vim from reading the rest of the file, it's much quicker
>   than using if-endif around the whole file.

---

It's also useful if you want to use a custom version of a default plugin.
By placing your custom version in a directory of the runtime path which comes before the one of the default plugin, yours will be sourced first (and set `g:loaded_...`); and when the default plugin will be sourced, the guard will prevent its interface from being installed and overwriting yours.

---

It can also be useful in a file under `autoload/`.
Suppose `autoload/someplugin.vim` contains the function `someplugin#func()`.
You call the function, which causes `autoload/someplugin.vim` to be sourced.
Now you call it a second time, but you make a typo:

```
:call someplugin#funx()
                    ^
                    ✘
```

The function won't be found and `E117` will be raised; but – without a guard – `autoload/someplugin.vim` will have been sourced a second time. This can cause an issue if the script tracks some state via a global or script-local variable which is initialized outside a function then updated at runtime; the state will be reset which may lead to all sorts of unexpected behaviors.

To make sure not to clash with a `g:loaded_` variable, you can use the prefix `autoloaded_` instead of `loaded_` (see [`vim-fugitive`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/3bf602b13d86b7aef57fec4a2df29467b61435cb/autoload/fugitive.vim#L4-L7) for an example) for files under `autoload/`.

---

Setting the `g:loaded_` variable allows you to inspect whether the plugin has been loaded.
As an example, I use this info to avoid configuring the plugin when it's temporarily disabled (e.g. with [`vim-matchup`](https://github.com/lacygoill/config/blob/05245b132a57072d75edd83072a0062185b3044c/.vim/plugin/matchup.vim#L1) and with [`vim-sandwich`](https://github.com/lacygoill/config/blob/05245b132a57072d75edd83072a0062185b3044c/.vim/after/plugin/sandwich.vim#L1)), typically when debugging some issue.